# Why the difference in code generation for bool = bool ? int : int

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, compiler-optimization

This code...

```
bool condSet(int cond, int a, int b) {
    return cond ? a : b;
}
```

..Generates for gcc 6.3...

```
    test    edx, edx
    setne   al 
    test    edi, edi
    jne     .L6
    rep ret
.L6:
    test    esi, esi
    setne   al
    ret
```

.. For icc 17...

```
    test      edi, edi
    cmovne    edx, esi
    mov       eax, 1
    test      edx, edx
    cmove     eax, edx
    ret
```

..And for clang 3.9

```
    test    edi, edi
    cmove   esi, edx
    test    esi, esi
    setne   al
    ret
```

<s>Why do we have theses differences, for a code pattern, that I'd expect to be common? They all rely on conditional instruction, setne, cmovne, cmove, but gcc has a branch as well, and they all use different order of instructions and parameters</s>.

What pass in the compiler is responsible for this code generation? Is the difference due to how the register allocation is done; how the general dataflow analysis is done; or do the compiler pattern match against this pattern when generating the code?

The code and the asm listings: https://godbolt.org/g/7heVGz

Comment: Perhaps because different people wrote the compiler code. Translation to assembler is not mandatory in form: the executable C code is only required to conform to the standard. All subject to compiler optimisation settings too. Which pass? C code has a preprocessor phase, but the compiler is one-pass.

Comment: There are many translations of Anna Karenina into English yet they use different words even for basic sentences. You would think that for a common sentence they would use the exact same words.

Comment: @RaymondChen,@WeatherVane. Sorry about being so imprecise. And my question is still vague, as I'm hoping for someone to enlighten me about how conditional instructions are selected in  a compiler. (That Anna Karenina metaphor was great). I deserved it. :-)

Comment: Part of the difference is that all three compilers target different calling conventions.

Comment: Have you attempted to discern which is the fastest?  Also, did you notice what happens if you change the output type (say to int)?

Comment: @RaymondChen They all target athe same calling convention (namely the SYS V x64 ABI) indeed, but that's irrelevant. As you said, there is no reason to believe that three different compilers give the same output :)

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: all three compilers make use the same `test/cmov` strategy like you'd expect if the return-type is changed to `int`, since the OP is using `-O3`  (except for clang where they used `-O1`?).   Not with identical code, but same number and type of instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed.  My point being that these differences between the compilers are due to a rather specific case.  Extrapolating this generically to "ternary operators" as the OP's question does seems a stretch.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: ah yes.  I forgot how the question was worded by the time I saw your comment (after I was done answering).  Good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the return type to `int` results in branchless code from all three compilers, using the `test/cmov` strategy.

I'd guess that gcc decides that booleanizing both sides of the conditional would be too much work, and decides to use a branch.  Maybe it doesn't realize that it's the *same* work, and the expression can actually be done the other way (select the right input and then booleanize that).

The code it makes does booleanize `b`, and only then tests the condition and booleanizes `a`.  So when `cond` is true, it actually runs both `test` / `setnz` pairs.

This smells like a missed-optimization bug.  (Or an optimization-run-amok bug, where it shoots itself in the foot by applying the return-type to both inputs of the `?:` instead of only to the result).

Reported as [GCC Bug 78947](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78947).

---

Until that's fixed, you can [get gcc to make code like clang / icc](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(colouriseAsm:'0',compileOnChange:'0'),source:'%0Abool+condSet_orig(int+cond,+int+a,+int+b)+%7B%0A++return+cond+%3F+a+:+b%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Abool+condSet_gcc_handhold(int+cond,+int+a,+int+b)+%7B%0A++int+tmp+%3D+cond+%3F+a+:+b%3B%0A++return+tmp%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:23.54577223656297,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang390,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-O1+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-Wall+-Wextra+-fverbose-asm'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+3.9.0',t:'0')),k:30.49177504634904,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:icc17,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-O3++-Wall+-Wextra+-fno-verbose-asm'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+icc+17',t:'0')),k:20.96245271708799,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-O3+-Wall+-Wextra+-fverbose-asm'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+6.3',t:'0')),k:25,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) by splitting it into two steps:

```
bool condSet(int cond, int a, int b) {
  int tmp = cond ? a : b;       // better asm from gcc this way
  return tmp;
}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about the fact that a bool needs to be represented as 1 or 0 in the registers; hence the extra instructions. Using int as return type, indeed produces "identical" code. I don't have a gcc bugzilla account at the moment, and my understanding of compilers are "patchy". Can you file the issue? I promise to file an issue myself, the next time I encounter a possible gcc bug.

Comment: @dannas: done.  I think gcc bugzilla account creation is still closed for spam reasons anyway, so IDK if you could have even if you'd wanted to :/

Comment: It is still possible to create a bugzilla account, the process has simply become manual, you have to contact overseers.