# Why if check is not being optimized

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, optimization, x86

Today I started playing around with branching that checks for two booleans. I was pretty sure that at some optimization level they will simply get added and then checked, but that is not the case with gcc and clang. Why isn't gcc optimizing two bool checks by replacing them with addition and one check? Let me show you the example:

```
void test(bool a, bool b)
{ 
    // Branch 1
    if (a && b)
    {
        std::cout << "Branch 1";
    }

    // Branch 2
    if (static_cast<int>(a) + static_cast<int>(b))
    {
        std::cout << "Branch 2";
    }
}
```

gcc (even with maximum optimization level) generates the following code for branch 1:

```
test   dil,dil
je     400794 <test(bool, bool)+0x14>
test   sil,sil
jne    4007b0 <test(bool, bool)+0x30>
```

while it generates the following code for the branch 2:

```
movzx  ebx,bl
movzx  ebp,bpl
add    ebx,ebp
jne    4007cf <test(bool, bool)+0x4f>
```

Shouldn't two branches (test + je) be slower than addition and branch (add + jne)?

Edit: what I really meant was a multiplication, because in case of true and false (1 + 0) addition gives true (1), but multiplication gives the correct result (0).

Comment: I didn't forget that, but how does it impact my code?

Comment: For starters, addition is not `&&`, it's `||`. Also, while not sure about current C++ standard, but the representation used to be `0` for `false` and everything else for `true`. Thus, you could have `-1` and `+1` for two true values, and adding those would not be very good. Similarly you could have `1` and `2` and bitwise `and` would not be good for those.

Comment: @Jester:  C++ `bool` variables can only be `true` or `false` (I *think* that is true for C `bool` values too.)  When converted to `int`, they *must* convert to 1 or 0 respectively.

Comment: Addition doesn't have same behaviour as boolean and. Multiplication is what you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't matter in this case. The "a && b" check gives two branches instead of one.

Comment: Possibly related to [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41323911/why-the-difference-in-code-generation-for-bool-bool-int-int); GCC doesn't optimize as efficiently as it could with `bool` values.

Comment: You don't want multiplication, @user. That will be slower. What's wrong with a simple bitwise AND? (Nothing. Nothing is wrong with it. That's what you should use if you want to force the optimization.)

Comment: That could be a missed optimization. Consider filing a bug report.

Comment: Why not edit the question to actually *use* `*` (or `&`) rather than say "that is what you meant".

Comment: @CodyGray: The compiler could optimize `bool * bool` into a bitwise and.

Comment: It "could", I agree, but that is almost a completely vacuous statement. It *could* also optimize `&&` into a bitwise AND, but it *doesn't*. That's what this entire question is about. GCC doesn't optimize `bool * bool` into a bitwise AND, either. (Other compilers do, though, so this is arguably a further bug in GCC's optimization heuristics surrounding `bool` types.) @martin

Answer (score 6):

At the level of the abstract machine, `&&` forces the second expression not to be evaluated if the first is false.  By the as-if rule, a compiler could choose to evaluate the second expression anyway - if it can prove it has defined behaviour (or the undefined behaviour won't matter) and no side effects; however the compiler writers have clearly decided that is not worth while.

If you *don't* want short-cutting, `&` can be helpful (with a comment).

Comment: Isn't that weird, that optimizer doesn't see that short-circuit is not needed? E.g. a && b will produce the same result as a + b (or a * b), so that can be used instead.

Comment: @ElvissStrazdins They might not do that because they are doing it generically.  `a && b && c && d && e && f` would be able to not evaluate anything but `a` if `a` is false where as with the multiplication it would have to evaluate/multiply all the result together.

Comment: @ElvissStrazdins: Note `a && b` will not produce the same result as `a + b` in every possible case. Consider `a = true` and `b = false`.

Comment: @ElvissStrazdins: Live demo to support Martin's point: http://cpp.sh/4bcim

Comment: And I was worried about `reinterpret_cast<bool>(2)` case when `&` is used, but gcc looks to emit error *"invalid cast from type 'int' to type 'bool'"* then, so the `&` together with `bool` looks safe.

Comment: Note that internally, on several platforms, gcc replaces `a&&b` with `a&b` early (see -fdump-tree-gimple). The back-end then choses to expand `(a&b)!=0` as 2 jumps, because it thinks that's more efficient on average.

Comment: @marc Why in the world would the back end think that? We're talking about x86 here, right? So in what universe would two jumps ever be more efficient than 1? Did I misread your comment as endorsing that decision?

Comment: @CodyGray What is more efficient depends on how often `a` is true. clang and gcc do the same here, so it can't be a random accident. But feel free to file bug reports with benchmarks showing that they are wrong.

Comment: @CodyGray: if `a` is always false, two jumps will be (slightly) faster.  Otherwise If one of the values is predictable and the other isn't, the overall result is unpredictable and the time will be dominated by an unpredicted branch.  If both values are unpredictable, two jumps will be a disaster.  I *think* gcc and clang are making a mistake here.

Comment: I still don't understand why two jumps would be faster. Are you counting the cost of zero-extending the byte value? That isn't strictly necessary: you could just do `test sil, dil`+`je`. How could that possibly be slower than `test sil, sil`+`je`+`test dil, dil`+`je`?

Comment: @CodyGray when you put it like that, it looks quite convincing (the situation may be a bit different when the booleans come from comparisons and are thus in flags instead of being already in registers). Could you file a report with either compiler so we can get an answer from the developers?

Answer (score 2):

> Why isn't gcc optimizing two bool checks by replacing them with
>   addition and one check?

The proposed optimization is incorrect. The *addition* isn't a proper replacement for `&&` operator, because the former will evaluate to `true` when *at least* (not both) one condition is `true`.

The question remains, how *could it be* optimized?

The C++ Standard guarantees that `bool` values are converted to `int` with defined values: `false` converts to `0` and `true` converts to `1`. Hence, the following construct is completely legal equivalent (assuming that both `a` and `b` are just `bool` variables):

```
if (a & b) // OK, integral promotions take place (bool ---> int)
```

Assuming that compiler always stores `bool` values with the same internal representation for `true` (e.g. `0x1`) and `false` (`0x0`), the condition may directly translated into x86 `test` instruction:

```
test    sil, dil
```

Here is the tricky part. Apparently, the GCC compiler has changed its behavior between mainline 4.6 and 4.7. Even with explicit casts to `int`, it keeps two separate jumps. The condition:

```
if (static_cast<int>(a) & static_cast<int>(b))
```

generates the code (GCC 6.2.0 with `-O3` optimization level):

```
test    dil, dil
je      .L1
test    sil, sil
je      .L1
```

On the other hand, both ICC and MSVC 2015 compilers do the "true" bitwise and:

```
movzx   eax, BYTE PTR b$[rsp]
test    al, BYTE PTR a$[rsp]
je  SHORT $LN6@main
```

which is also the case for GCC prior to version 4.7 (GCC 4.6.3 with `-O3`):

```
movzx   edi, dil
test    esi, edi
```

Comment: Looks to me like [a missed optimization opportunity](https://godbolt.org/g/JcJAZG) for both GCC and Clang. As you point out, both ICC and MSVC get it correct and emit a simple `test` instruction. Someone should file a defect report for both GCC and Clang. I can't think of a single reason why it would be necessary to test the values independently, and it certainly is not optimal.

Answer (score -2):

You forget that the logical operators does [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

For logical and, if the left-hand side is false, then the right-hand side is not evaluated.

Comment: True but irrelevant since both are booleans already, nothing to "evaluate", the compiler could very well optimize it.

Comment: How does evaluation order impact my code? They checked in order or just added will produce the same result. There is no way, that the results will differ, so this can be optimized.